# How to click to remove objects from array list in processing

Tags: java, arraylist, processing

Im trying to create a game where you click on an object to remove it. The code below is what I have for this section of the game but it gives the following error:

> "Cannot invoke remove(int) on the array type mouseClick.Enemy[]"

Here is my code:

```
void mousePressed() {
    for(int i = 0; i < enemies.length; i++){
        float distance = dist(mouseX, mouseY, enemies[i].x, enemies[i].y); 

        if(distance < enemies[i].radius + 10) {
            enemies.remove(i);
        }
    }
}
```

Are there any other methods/functions I could use to implement this into my game?

Comment: The error message you're getting makes it pretty clear that you've got an array, not an `ArrayList`.

Answer (score 2):

As azurefrog said:
The remove function can't be used on arrays. However, you can use that function with arrayLists. You can make a new ArrayList like this:

```
ArrayList<Enemy> yourList = new ArrayList<Enemy>();
```

Of course "yourList" is just a name you can choose. Just as Enemy is the class I assumed you are using. If you want an object out of that list you would also have to use

```
yourList.get(i);
```

instead of

```
yourList[i];
```

Hope this helps!